# Custom permalink based on custom post type fields

Tags: posts, customization

I'm workin on new webiste and I got stuck :(

Basically I've created a custom post type for products with custom fields etc.

Each product has a main category and subcategory - selected from

```
<select>
<option value="category1">category 1</option>
<option value="category2">category 2</option>
</select>

<select>
<option value="subcategory1">subcategory 1</option>
<option value="subcategory1">subcategory 2</option>
</select>
```

inside editor.

The subcategory is based on category.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get permalinks based on both: category and subcategory fe.

```
domain.com/products/category2/subcategory1/product
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Show us some code. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I read about taxonomies, but that doesn't seem to resolve my problem. With one-level slug taxonomies would be great, but I've two...

Comment: You don't have to write "The subcategory is based on category." 
What URL structure you are getting when you view product?

Comment: @Gangesh - domain.com/products/name-of-the-product

EDIT:
/products/ - name of the custom post type
/name-of-the-product - title of page created under custom post type

Comment: Its not exact what you need but very close.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/insert-category-of-taxonomy-between-custom-post-type-and-post

Answer (score 0):

Look at the filter for rewrite_rules_array and add a re-write rule to re-write /products/category-name/sub-category-name/product-name to index.php?pagename=product-name.  You might need to grab the category-name and sub-category-name too if your product-names are not unique.

Then add a query var for product-name using the query_vars filter.

Once you've done that in your new post type template you can just access the product-name query var (and the others) using get_query_var. And display the correct record.

Without coding the answer for you that's and outline of how I've done exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

I tried to rewrite permalink, is it correct? http://pastebin.com/pAXZw2mH

Comment: You don't know what the query vars are when the re-write rules are added.  You only know when the page (or post) is generated.  The rewrite rule should be something like this:

array('produkty/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[3]&product_category=$matches[1]&product_sub_category=$matches[1]